# check file in framework

Tags: php, frameworks, include

I see most frameworks in PHP using "`file_exists`" in "class loader" before including the file or return an error.

Does this have any practical application or is it just a form of debugging errors to the "inexperienced" user ?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just good practice as it creates a catchable error where the framework can exit gracefully.

Comment: a framework do not necessarily need to own a prior verification of the file
correct?

Comment: What happens if the file hasn't been copied e.g. due to an FTP error for some reason? Sure, it's not urgently necessary, but it doesn't do any harm either. In those rare cases where it kicks in, it will help.

Comment: My fear is almost this...
but if there is no upload and they are not changed there would be no problem in omit the "file_exists"
correct?

where maintenance put the entire system offline to prevent error occurring in the include file